# Daemon setTimeout in js

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am writing a node.js library that requires setup in order to run. I have used setTimeout to show a warning if the setup function isn't run within 5 seconds.

However, this makes the program wait for 5 seconds before exiting, even if all the other code is finished.

I want to show a warning message iff the setup function hasn't been called and the program is still running after 5 seconds. Is there a way to do this with vanilla JS?

```
const done = new Event(); // Event is a simple class I made for a one-time event multicast

function setup() {
  done.emit();
}

const timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => showWarning(), 5000);
done.subscribe(() => {
  clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
});

console.log("The program should end here");

// The program keeps going for 5 seconds even after the last statement
```

Comment: make setup async, then await done.emit() or what ever you are using to check its finished, then if its finished clear the timeout.

Comment: @ColinHale that is what I am doing already. The problem is if the user never calls setup(). Then the timeout never gets cleared and the program keeps running for 5 seconds

Comment: I guess i am misunderstanding what you are trying to do then. seems like it is working as intended? if they don't run setup then they get the warning. are you wanting to clear the timeout once the setup finishes?

Comment: Shouldn't that be something that is part of the documentation? There are so many modules that require some kind of setup, and I don't know any that would exit the program if the user doesn't do the setup. Why is it that important that you think that you need to exit the program if the user does not do the setup correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this makes the program wait for 5 seconds before exiting, even if all the other code is finished.

You can utilize [`timeout.unref()`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref):

> When called, the active Timeout object will not require the Node.js event loop to remain active. If there is no other activity keeping the event loop running, the process may exit before the Timeout object's callback is invoked. Calling `timeout.unref()` multiple times will have no effect.

So `const timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => showWarning(), 5000); timeoutHandle.unref();`

This will prevent the `setTimeout` to keep the process active.